# Dual internet 2xWAN (RRAS Nat) worked, but teaming does not work

Tags: network-teaming

I have setup a server and I have 2 internet connections, I have tried several attempts at getting this to work properly.

In the RRAS I have successfully added into NAT 2x WAN NICs and a LAN NIC and I was seeing traffic being Sent & Received from both Internet WAN Routers, it was a little chaotic and believe had a lot of lost packets as I kept having to F5 websites.. 
but nonetheless it worked well enough to give me impressions of a faster internet.. (4pm-11pm internet here is horrid! so the 2nd connection helped I could see the benefit... Just F5 a few times tho!)

When I configure RRAS to have the 1 Teamed WAN for some reason the 2nd NIC wont receive any data. I can see it sending packets when browsing websites but nothing is received. I can see what NIC is doing what from the Team Configuration window.

I read a great document about NIC teaming but am still unclear on a few things. I have tried several IP configurations.

I hope to have a few questions answered.

for clarity I am using windows server 2016, NIC Teaming is Switch Independent Mode, Dynamic.

Questions.

1. Do Both WAN Internet routers need to be on the same Subnet Mask? eg 255.255.255.0
2. Does the LAN need to be on the same Subnet mask as WAN? eg 255.255.255.0
3. Should both WAN Routers be on the same IP Address Range or Different, EG 
   WAN 1 Router IP:192.168.0.1 / SN:255.255.255.0 / GW:192.168.0.1 and have
   WAN 2 Router 192.168.0.2 / SN:255.255.255.0 / GW:192.168.0.2
   or should WAN 2 Router be
   WAN 2 Router 192.168.1.1 / SN:255.255.255.0 / GW:192.168.1.1

I am hoping to get the right answer so I can correctly configure my routers and network and then properly troubleshoot why it doesn't work.

Thankyou Kindly,.
Shaun

Answer (score 1):

So after much trial and error, I ended up disabling the TEAMING and installed pfSense in favor of load balancing and it worked fine.. I now have both networks contributing